# Android - button text from up to down?

Tags: android

is there any way how to set text on button not from left to right, but from top to down?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, *that's not possible*.

However, if you find a solution I would not recommend using it. You're breaking the common way of how Android applications are meant to be designed. If an Android application is meant to be designed that way, Google would have a way to create a `Button` like you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can statically specify button **layout_width as some 5 dp or lower**...and **layout_height as wrap_content** so that text will wrap next line..

then use setText..

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you create an Image, I mean a .png (and store it in drawable). In this png you store your word the way you want to be displayed. Then set that png as the button background then it may work for you.